# Use request.user in class Index(TemplateView)

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to implement this:

```
class Index(TemplateView):
    if request.user.role == 'admin':
        template_name = 'index/admin/index.html'
    elif request.user.role == 'ff':
        template_name = 'index/firefighter/index.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'index/dev/index.html'

@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return super(Index, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

And i don't have idea that how implement it... Any help? This Code not work have the error: "Undefined name 'request' "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your template in the `get_template_names()` method:

```
from django.utils.decorator import method_decorator

class Index(TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self, *args, **kwargs):
        roles_urls = {'admin': 'index/admin/index.html',
                      'ff': 'index/firefighter/index.html'}
        default = 'index/dev/index.html'
        return [roles_urls.get(self.request.user.role, default)]

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Index, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: It's work... but 'from django.utils.decorator method_decorator' should be 'from django.utils.decorator import method_decorator
'